# enabling Spanning-Tree or not

Tags: switch, redundancy, spanning-tree, loop-device

do you think is wise or stupid keeping the rapid spanning tree enabled for just two switches in this image? https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIG0i.jpg
 As you can see the switches are not redundant each other but are connected simply because one has finished the ports avaible.
Two swithes can't generate a loop isn't it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You should only disable spanning tree if you do not use Layer2.

If all ports on your switch are Layer3 interfaces, you cannot have a loop and your endpoints are routed, each with a private subnet. Otherwise keep it on!

**Update**
There is a difference between OFF and not configured, with 2 switches I would leave them unconfigured, in most switches disabling RSTP may be possible, but STP will still be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* disable STP but you *shouldn't*.

Why? When someone connects two switch ports together your network will go down without STP. Leaving it on doesn't hurt a bit.

Answer (score 0):

As you have just 2 switches, connected with single cable, you can disable STP.

However the STP can prevent your environment from accidential loop caused by inserting another cable to both switches making additional path. The overhead of STP is really low these days. If you're sure that such a possibility won't happen or is very very unlikely, disable STP. Otherwise leave it running.

Answer (score 0):

So what happens if someone inadvertently makes another connection between the switches? What happens when you add a third switch and forget that STP is disabled on the first two?

There's no good reason to disable STP.